# How to scan searchable pdf from image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ocr, swift5

I want to scan documents with the tesseract framework in swift and generate pdf file that could searchable.

actually, I am using this code to convert image to text but I want to generate pictures in the main format but the format will change with convert to text and generate the pdf file.
my code is:

```css
   func recognizeText(image:UIImage) ->String {
        var str = "0"
        if let tessaract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
            tessaract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
            tessaract.pageSegmentationMode = .auto
            tessaract.image = image
            tessaract.recognize()
            str = tessaract.recognizedText ?? "0000"
        }
        return str
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using OCR to make the text in your scanned images searchable, you will probably need a to use a library or SDK that is able to generate PDF output.

The output will probably be a multi-layered PDF, where one layer will hold the recognized text and the layer above that will hold the images scanned previous, allowing the PDF to be searchable.

There are multiple libraries that can be used to generate PDF, one that I can suggest (as I work for the vendor) is the LEADTOOLS toolkit, which has both OCR and Document Conversion features:
https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/pdf/convert-images-searchable-pdf-ocr/